# Errors referring to type "_": "Cannot assign value of type '[Value]' to type '_?'"

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm trying to merge two `Dictionary` objects. When they both have a `value` for a `key`, I would like the second `Dictionay`'s value to overwrite the first, with a couple of exceptions:

- When both values are `Dictionary` objects, I'd like them to be merged, using the same method recursively.
- When both values are `Array` objects, I'd like them to be concatenated.

My code is as follows:

```
extension Dictionary where Key:Hashable, Value:AnyObject {
    func merge(with second: [Key : Value]) -> [Key : Value] {
        var resultDictionary = self

        for (key, value) in second {
            switch value {
            case let newDict as [Key : Value]:
                if let oldDict = resultDictionary[key] as? [Key : Value] {
                    resultDictionary[key] = oldDict.merge(with: newDict) // 1
                } else {
                    resultDictionary[key] = newDict // 2
                }

            case let newArray as [Value]:
                if let oldArray = resultDictionary[key] as? [Value] {
                    resultDictionary[key] = oldArray + newArray // 3
                } else {
                    resultDictionary[key] = newArray // 4
                }

            default:
                resultDictionary[key] = value
            }
        }

        return resultDictionary
    }
}
```

I'm getting on the commented lines:

1. Cannot convert value of type '[Key : Value]' to expected argument type '[_ : _]'
2. Cannot assign value of type '[Key : Value]' to type '_?'
3. Cannot assign value of type '[Value]' to type '_?'
4. Cannot assign value of type '[Value]' to type '_?'

I think all these errors are the same, if not very closely related. It seems that the underscore is used as a type here, but I'm not what that means in this context. I thought that an underscore was only used to signify an unused variable.

Comment: Underscore here means the compiler could not uniquely determine the type, often because the type would be impossible. As Sulthan notes, in your case, `Value` would have to equivalent to `[Key: Value]` in order for the first `case` to function. That's not possible (it makes the type infinitely recursive). So you wind up with `_` in the error message.

Comment: The constraint  `Key:Hashable` is redundant, that is already required by `struct Dictionary`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can realize your error by splitting the expression into two:

```
let newValue: [Key: Value] = oldDict.merge(with: newDict)
resultDictionary[key] = newValue // 1
```

Note that now you are assigning a `[Key: Value]` dictionary into something that expects type `Value`.

You need a cast

```
resultDictionary[key] = newValue as? Value // 1
```

From type perspective, this is all very strange. You should not be trying cast a dictionary to some provided type.

Why don't add the function only to dictionaries which have `AnyObject` as values?

```
extension Dictionary where Key:Hashable, Value == AnyObject
```

and then

```
resultDictionary[key] = newValue as AnyObject
```

The cast is now a compile-time cast, nice and safe.

Comment: Thank you for your solution and the updates. I'd never considered compile-time casts before. The run-time type seemed unsafe as I was implementing it but I wasn't sure of what my options were. Thanks again.

Comment: @JoshParadroid You should now that by casting to `AnyObject` you are actually casting the dictionary to Obj-C `NSDictionary`. In Swift, a dictionary is a value type and is not an `AnyObject`. Using plain `Any` might be a better solution in this case.

Comment: I actually needed to store a non-object value in there, so I'd switched it anyway. It's always nice to know how the inner workings of Swift work though so thanks.